# URL for latest stable Go release

Tags: go

Is there is a permanent URL that points to current latest linux binary release of Go?

I am writing an ansible script which should download the latest Go release and install it. In the Go download site "https://golang.org/dl/" I could see only release specific download links.

I am wondering if there a link like "https://dl.google.com/go/latest.linux-amd64.tar.gz" available?

If not any suggestion on how to script fetching the latest golang version and install it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As found [here](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/getgo#readme-usage), Google has a Linux installer to install Go on linux:

https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/getgo/installer_linux

This installer fetches the latest version of Go and installs it. Seems like this is the easiest way as of now to install the latest go version on Linux.

The newest official method to fetch the file and execute it is:

```
curl -LO https://get.golang.org/$(uname)/go_installer
chmod +x go_installer
./go_installer
rm go_installer
```

Comment: It seems the package is broken and not actively maintained. Someone decided to add a second line encompassing the date to the API response which this installer does not expect. But as others have noted here in this Q&A, the retrieved version number is ithe version the website is running, it does not have to be the latest stable you are looking for. Here is a workaround: `curl -LO get.golang.org/$(uname)/go_installer && chmod +x go_installer && ./go_installer --version $(curl https://go.dev/dl/?mode=json | jq -r '.[0].version') && rm go_installer`

Answer (score 27):

You can download the latest stable Go version in one go :)

```
wget "https://dl.google.com/go/$(curl https://go.dev/VERSION?m=text).linux-amd64.tar.gz"
```

Comment: `wget "https://dl.google.com/go/$(curl 'https://golang.org/VERSION?m=text').linux-amd64.tar.gz"` useful

Comment: This method doesn't work anymore. The URLs have changed. `https://go.dev/dl/<VERSION>` and for fetching version `https://go.dev/VERSION?m=text`

Comment: @Shabirmean the /VERSION?m=text url is not the right one to use -- it returns the version of go backing the go.dev website, which right now is 1.18.1, a bleed edge version that is not yet available for download! The URL you really want to use is `https://go.dev/dl/?mode=json`. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51135 for details.

Comment: `curl "https://dl.google.com/go/$(curl https://go.dev/dl/?mode=json | grep -o 'go.*.linux-amd64.tar.gz' | head -n 1 | tr -d '\r\n' )"`

Comment: A simpler version taking care of the additional lines in the response: `wget "https://dl.google.com/go/$(curl https://go.dev/VERSION?m=text | head -n1).linux-amd64.tar.gz"`

Answer (score 4):

You can generate the latest url with :

```
https://dl.google.com/go{{ version }}.{{ os }}-{{ arch }}.tar.gz
```

**os:** linux, darwin, windows, freebsd
**arch:** amd64, 386, armv6l, arm64, s390, ppc64le

and for the latest stable version you can fetch the value with curl or something else from the url :

```
https://golang.org/VERSION?m=text
```

Here is an ansible playbook as an example :

```
---
- hosts: server
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    version : "latest"
    arch: arm64
    os: linux

    latest_version_url: https://golang.org/VERSION?m=text
    archive_name: "{{ filename_prefix }}.{{ os }}-{{ arch }}.tar.gz"
    download_url: https://dl.google.com/go/{{ archive_name }}
    bin_path: /usr/local/go/bin

  tasks:
    - name: Get filename prefix with latest version
      set_fact:
        filename_prefix: "{{ lookup('url', latest_version_url, split_lines=False) }}"
      when: version == "latest"
    
    - name: Get filename prefix with fixed version
      set_fact:
        filename_prefix: go{{ version }}
      when: version != "latest"
    
    - name: Try to get current go version installed
      command: go version
      register: result
      changed_when: false

    - name: Set current_version var to the current
      set_fact:
        current_version: "{{ result.stdout.split(' ')[2] }}"
      when: result.failed == false

    - name: Set current_version var to none
      set_fact:
        current_version: "none"
      when: result.failed == true

    - debug:
        var: current_version

    - name: Download and extract the archive {{ archive_name }}
      become: true
      unarchive:
          src: "{{ download_url }}"
          dest: /usr/local
          remote_src: yes
      when: current_version != filename_prefix
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. They don't want the latest version *number*, they want the latest version *installer*

Comment: You are right, just the url [https://golang.org/VERSION?m=text](https://golang.org/VERSION?m=text) is not enough, but it was the missing part from the other answer to make a script, I have updated my answer to be more complete.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like many answers here are outdated and make wrong assumptions.

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51135

> VERSION is the version running the website, not latest version to download.

## Download for Linux

```bash
os="linux"
arch="amd64"
ext="tar.gz"
curl -LO go.dev/dl/$(curl https://go.dev/dl/?mode=json \
                     | jq -r '.[0].version').$os-$arch.$ext
```

(On Windows you have your winget and on MacOS you have your Homebrew. I don't know why you are here reading this.)

## Installer for Linux

And here is the workaround for the installer Murli posted.

```bash
curl -LO get.golang.org/$(uname)/go_installer \
&& chmod +x go_installer \
&& ./go_installer \
     --version $(curl https://go.dev/dl/?mode=json \
                 | jq -r '.[0].version') \
&& rm go_installer
```

As I wrote in my comment below the answer:

> It seems the package is broken and not actively maintained. Someone decided to add a second line encompassing the date to the API response which this installer does not expect.

If it still works and it is convenient for you, you may use it. If it breaks, you are on your own. Usually I would file an issue, but I don't know where to file an issue regarding this (it's  not Github, Gitlab or in any another way obvious) and its late, so it will have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

I use the below for Linux:

```bash
wget "https://go.dev/dl/$(curl 'https://go.dev/VERSION?m=text').linux-amd64.tar.gz" && sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go && sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go*.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

There is also a [cross-platform solution built by the Go Community](https://go.googlesource.com/tools/+/master/cmd/getgo/):

```bash
curl -LO https://get.golang.org/$(uname)/go_installer && chmod +x go_installer && ./go_installer && rm go_installer
```

Comment: Does not work for arm64

Comment: No it won't, I hard-coded it for amd64 because that's what I use. Just replace `amd64` with `arm64` in the script above and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to defer to something like [jlund/ansible-go](https://github.com/jlund/ansible-go), or copy over the parts of that role that you need.

Comment: Seems like this role needs "go" version to be specified in "go_version_target" variable. It won't just fetch the latest "go" version.

Comment: Quoting the package description: "Ansible role that installs Go (http://golang.org/). The latest stable release that has been compiled for x86 64-bit Linux systems is installed by default, and different platforms and versions are supported by modifying the role variables." Is that at odds with the source code?

Comment: In " ansible-go/defaults/main.yml", the default version points to "go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz". The latest version as of now is go1.10.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz 

The default version was updated a year ago. Effectively one needs to manually update what is the latest version in this package also!!!